# PHP to list all Packages/Procedures/Functions and also its body of content in a script

Tags: php, sql, plsql, db2

I need a quick PHP script to list down all packages/procedures/functions including its body of content so that any line of SQL code can easily be found by using CTRL+F.

I have like 100+ procedures and functions in a db/schema which is hard to find for a specific line of SQL inside the procedures script. Example like toad package viewer:

[image: Toad]

The php script will loop through all packages and show their scripts like:

```
SET CURRENT SCHEMA = JCONVEY;

SET CURRENT PATH = SYSIBM,SYSFUN,SYSPROC,SYSIBMADM,DB2INST1;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE JCONVEY.ENDSTAGE_SENDMAIL (
    BAID IN VARCHAR(4000) DEFAULT 'BPP',
    EMAILTITLE IN   VARCHAR(4000),
    SQLMSG IN   VARCHAR(4000),
    RECEMAIL IN VARCHAR(4000),
    CASEID IN   VARCHAR(4000),
    UNIQUEID IN VARCHAR(4000) DEFAULT '',
    CC_TO IN    VARCHAR(4000) DEFAULT '',
    HISTTYPE IN DECFLOAT(16) DEFAULT 99,
    USRID IN    VARCHAR(4000) DEFAULT '*SYSTEM',
    ATT_ID IN   VARCHAR(4000) DEFAULT '0',
    MAQ_TYP IN  VARCHAR(12) DEFAULT NULL )
IS
subject VARCHAR2(200);
msg  CLOB;
```

Comment: is `select  *from  all_source` what you need?

Comment: did you try something?

Comment: @hotfix thats it! thank you, but a php code displaying all the content will make ctrl+f easier, will write a php for that later on...

Comment: plsql and db2?!?

Answer (score 0):

Answer based on @hotfix above, php script can be used like this:

```
<?php
$conn = db2_connect('DB', 'db2inst1','password' );
db2_exec($conn, 'set schema jconvey');

$stmt = db2_prepare($conn,'
    select text from all_source where text is not null
    ');
$result = db2_execute($stmt);

if($result)
{
    while ($row = db2_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {
        echo '-------------------------------------------------------<br><br><br>';
        echo $row['TEXT'].'<br><br><br>';
    }   
}
```